# Escaping variables in path names using csh

Tags: linux, command-line, csh

I am trying to create paths using variables as follows:

```
set var=foo
set path="/home/user/prefix_$var_suffix/bar"
```

What is the proper way to embed the variable so that it doesn't keep reading past the `_`. As a bonus, is there a syntax that will work for perl and csh (or bash at the least)?

Comment: Updated question to say Perl not Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly braces to delimit the variable. This works in csh and all Bourne-style shells (including bash). It also works in Perl.

```
set path="/home/user/prefix_${var}_suffix/bar"
```

Another way is to end the quotes:

```
set path="/home/user/prefix_""$var""_suffix/bar"
```

In Perl you would have to use the `.` concatenation operator:

```
$path = "/home/user/prefix_".$var."_suffix/bar"
```

Note that you shouldn't use `path` as a variable name in your `csh` script, as that's used for the search path to find executables.

Comment: Ah, sorry, meant Perl not Python. Can I have the opening brace outside the `$` if I want (for editor purposes)?

Comment: It also works in Perl. No, you can't wrap the braces around the variable (that's how PHP does it, but not shells or Perl).

Comment: You might want to add that in Perl you can also escape with forward slash:
`$path = "/home/user/prefix_$var\_suffix/bar"`
but I don't see a syntax to escape in both Perl and csh.

Comment: @Stuart Minor nit, that's a backslash.